# jquery slideToggle does not go back to original settings

Tags: jquery, html, css

I developed the following simple jQuery menu:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".button, .button_menu_01").on('click', function () {
        $(this).next('.panel').slideToggle(500);
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.button {
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     float: right;
     background-color: fuchsia;
}

.panel { 
     width: 100%;
     padding-left: 0%;
     font-weight: bold;
     overflow: hidden;
     display:none;
}

.button_menu_01 {
     padding-left: 1%;
     background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="button">Menu</div>
<div class="panel"> 
    <div class="button_menu_01">1.0 Main Menu</div>
    <div class="panel">
        <div>1.1 Sub Menu</div> 
        <div class="button_menu_01">1.2 Sub Menu</div>
        <div class="panel">
            <div> 1.2.1 Sub Menu</div>
            <div> 1.2.2 Sub Menu</div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also find the `jsfiddle` [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9bc0w3dL/11/). 
All of this works fine so far.

---

Now when I drill through the menu till `1.2.1 Sub Menu` and `1.2.2 Sub Menu` and after that I click on the main menu `.button` the entire menu collapses. Now I click again on the main menu `.button` and the entire menu expands **including** all `Sub Menus`.

My target is that once the main menu `.button` is pressed to collapse the entire menu that it goes back to its original settings so once you click again it only displays `1.0 Main Menu` like it does when you click it for the first time.

What do I have to change in my code to achive this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to adjust your code to do slightly different things depending on whether your panel is currently active or inactive:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button, .button_menu_01").on('click', function() {
    // Grab the associated panel
    var $panel = $(this).next('.panel');

    // If it's visible, hide it as well as all its subpanels
    if ($panel.is(':visible')) {
      $panel.add($panel.find('.panel')).slideUp(500).removeClass('active');
    } 
    // Otherwise, simply show it
    else {
      $panel.slideDown(500).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
  background-color: fuchsia;
}

.panel {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0%;
  font-weight: bold;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}

.button_menu_01 {
  padding-left: 1%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="button">Menu</div>
<div class="panel">

  <div class="button_menu_01">1.0 Main Menu</div>
  <div class="panel">

    <div>1.1 Sub Menu</div>

    <div class="button_menu_01">1.2 Sub Menu</div>
    <div class="panel">

      <div> 1.2.1 Sub Menu</div>
      <div> 1.2.2 Sub Menu</div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man. Works perfectly. I also updated it here https://jsfiddle.net/9bc0w3dL/15/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
{
 $(".button").on('click', function ()
  {
   $(this).next('.panel').slideToggle(500);
   $(this).next('.panel').find('.panel').slideUp(500);
   $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
 $(".button_menu_01").on('click', function ()
  {
   $(this).next('.panel').slideToggle(500);
   $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.button {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 float: right;
 background-color: fuchsia;
}

.panel{
 width: 100%;
 padding-left: 0%;
 font-weight: bold;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: none;
}

.button_menu_01 {
 padding-left: 1%;
 background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="button">
 Menu
</div>
<div class="panel">
 <div class="button_menu_01">
  1.0 Main Menu
 </div>
 <div class="panel sub">
  <div>
   1.1 Sub Menu
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="button_menu_01">
  1.2 Sub Menu
 </div>
 <div class="panel sub">
  <div>
   1.2.1 Sub Menu
  </div>
  <div>
   1.2.2 Sub Menu
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Replace Your Code with this one

Hope it will work for you

Comment: I believe this will only "collapse all" when clicking the root menu, not for the in-between submenus themselves.

Comment: Please look at my edited answer I had made some changes just a little change in html structure and js